# Enabling Bridging Mode in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to enable Bridging Mode by following this guide (http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/bridged_networking.html) but I am not seeing the Bridge Adapter IP after I have completed the steps.

Here are the steps I performed to try to set up the Bridge Adapter:

1. Shut down Vagrant
2. Opened up my Vagrantfile to add the lines:
   `Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
   config.vm.network :bridged
   end`
3. Saved Vagrantfile
4. Started up Vagrant
5. Ran command `ifconfig` and noticed that I don't have a Bridge Adapter IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize that I needed to `vagrant up` so the changes in Vagrantfile can take in effected.